# c# how to reduce Fingerprint template byte size to fit in mifare 1k card using digital persona one touch sdk

Tags: c#, nfc, fingerprint, mifare

Am trying to enroll fingerprint template using digital persona 4500 and one touch SDK and the size of the template I keep getting is 1632 bytes , how can I reduce/compress the size of the template in byte array to a less than 800 bytes so I can store it in an NFC/RFID MIFARE 1k card.

```
protected override void Process(DPFP.Sample Sample)
            {
                base.Process(Sample);

                // Process the sample and create a feature set for the enrollment purpose.
                DPFP.FeatureSet features = ExtractFeatures(Sample, DPFP.Processing.DataPurpose.Enrollment);

                // Check quality of the sample and add to enroller if it's good
                if (features != null) try
                {
                    MakeReport("The fingerprint feature set was created.");
                    Enroller.AddFeatures(features);     // Add feature set to template.
                }
                finally {
                    UpdateStatus();

                    // Check if template has been created.
                    switch(Enroller.TemplateStatus)
                    {
                        case DPFP.Processing.Enrollment.Status.Ready:   // report success and stop capturing
                            OnTemplate(Enroller.Template);
                            SetPrompt("Click Close, and then click Fingerprint Verification.");
                            Stop();
                            break;

                        case DPFP.Processing.Enrollment.Status.Failed:  // report failure and restart capturing
                            Enroller.Clear();
                            Stop();
                            UpdateStatus();
                            OnTemplate(null);
                            Start();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Maybe there's method in SDK to convert proprietary template to ISO template (for instance ISO FMC CS which is the smallest size). Is there a public doc on SDK ?

Comment: The SDK is not public, The Template conversion is not supported  by the SDK, few methods I can see here are ConvertToANSI381(Sample, ref byte[]) and ConvertToPicture(Sample, ref byte [])

Comment: I need to convert the byte array to a string or hexadecimal which gives me (3264 character)which I have to store in the nfc/rfid 1k card and convert them back to byte array for verification, which is working very well. All the conversions I have tried gives me the same number of bytes, I can't figure out how to reduce it to less than 400bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion. How about you save e.g. only the 'Identity NO' (unique key) of a person into the nfc/rfid mifare card then have e.g. an SQL based database somewhere where you save the same 'Identity NO' against the fingerprint templates of the person such that when the mifare card is presented for verification, the 'Identity NO' it holds is used to retrieve fingerprint templates saved against the same 'Identity NO' for verification from the SQL database?

Comment: Thanks but I can't do that, I need the fingerprint data in the card for offline functionality of the system, I only want to set up one server and multiple client PCs so the system shouldn't fetch the prints from a db

Comment: Then in that case you may need to opt out of the nfc/rfid 1K mifare card and opt for another one with a bigger writable memory size.

Comment: I can get a mifare 4k but that will only allow me to store one fingerprint data(which is 3264 bytes) but that's if I ran out of options, I need to store at least 2 fingerprint templates.

Comment: Just a quick one, with your digitalpersona API, is it creating a consolidated fingerprint template from 4 fingerprint templates? As in you place finger 4 times on your fingerprint reader for it to generate a fingerprint template from that one finger?

Comment: Right, it takes 4 fingerprint samples

Comment: I dont know if it is possible to make it ask only for 2 samples to create a fingerprint template. I am hoping by this approach the bytes of the consolidated fingerprint template will be smaller so that you can in the end manage to save 2 fingerprint templates in your mifare card. The other option (though not good) is to save the sample itself by converting it to a template because it will be smaller in size.

Answer (score -1):

you managed to solve your problem.

I also need to reduce, because I use the BIOMINI PLUS 2 register and now I want to use the digital persona 4500, but the template is bigger.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30756505)